# How to attach 2D object to a rope?

Tags: unity, 2d

I was wondering, how I can attach a game object (player) to another object (a rope) when both came in contact in Unity. I think it should be done with a OnTriggerEnter2D, but doesn't know how I should implement this in code.

*UPDATE*
After receiving a answer from @Timelord64, I tried to get it work. When the player came in contact with the rope, the trigger will be called and the code will does his job. But the problem now is, that the player will not be connected to the rope at the position he is jumping. The only thing it does now, is set the Player gameObject as a child of the rope. When the player gets in contact with the rope and after that the player will be in idle, you will see the player move a little bit to left and right, the same direction as the rope (rope has a hinge joint 2D component).

My question for know is, how I can attach the player directly to the object? Also is there a way you can jump from the rope to something else?

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Swing : MonoBehaviour {

    // trigger event within rope
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) { // send in the other collider (should always work)
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") { // used a tag to ID collider as player
            other.transform.SetParent(this.transform); // set gameobject as others parent
            other.gameObject.SendMessage("trigger send");
        }
    }

}
```

The code is a component from the rope game object.

Comment: I recently published an asset that could help you accomplish this if you are still interested: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/slug/189679

Answer (score 1):

First big thing to remember is that collider and trigger events should be called with the "collider other" in the brackets if we want to work with whatever caused the collision or trigger.

```
// trigger event within rope
OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) // send in the other collider (should always work)
{
    if(other.tag = "tagUsedToIdentifyRope") // used a tag to ID collider as player
    {
        other.Transform.SetParent(this.transform); // set gameobject as others parent
    }
}
```

Always good to check the tag. Use a system that makes it easy to tell between what we should be allowing to interact, and what shouldn't.

From there, we reference the transform of the "other collider", and set its parent to the ropes transform.

I have just used this system to randomly generate weapon pieces onto a main body, which in itself can access all the parts attached to it, so I hope this has helped. You may have to customize it to your suited needs.

For example, you will want to move the player transform to exactly where the player will be attaching to the rope, so it looks like they are actually swinging. My system works for a weapon base, attaching a barrel, scope, silencer and magazine, but it works best because all the parts move together as a whole from there on.

An easy way to get this working for player swinging on rope is to have a second gameobject placed right at the end of the rope, where the player is intending to grab. Use something like

```
GameObject anchor; // pivot point game object
```

to store an anchor point on the rope, and

```
other.Transform.SetParent(anchor.transform); // set anchor others parent
```

to set the anchor transform. Hope this helps

Comment: Should the rope be a child of the player or is it ok to have the rope and the player as parents. I used `SendMessage` to check if there is something happen and it is. When the player is in idle, after you triggered the code, you will see them move a little bit to left and right, the same direction as the rope (rope has a motor with hinge joint). But it will not snap to its game object. @Timelord64

Comment: I looked also at your part of the anchor, but doesn't know how to achieve this. Maybe you can help me with it?

Comment: Can't figure out image linking to show you a visual example, but all you need to do is have a game object on your rope exactly where the player is to attach, and have the rope as its parent. The game object can be empty, as we are only using its transform.

If you then parent the player to the anchor, the player will move with the rope. It is entirely to you how you go about snapping the player (so it looks like the player actually hangs from the anchor).